# Travelling in Schengen area while waiting for permit of stay renewal in Italy

Tags: schengen, italy, permits, schengen-visas

I am a non-European living in Italy. Currently, my permesso di soggiorno has expired and I have applied for a new one. However, I need to go to another Schengen country for a job meeting before I get my permesso di soggiorno. Do you think if it is possible for me to get a temporary permit to travel in Schengen area from the Questura office in my city if I supply my claim with proper documentation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: depends the Questura, some can give you a temporary permit, some not. Any chance you can get your new permit before your trip?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible and you need to apply for a residence permit called: *Permesso di soggiorno provvisorio*.

Here is a list of documents you need to submit to the police station:

1. The expired residence card
2. The receipt of the post office for the renewal request
3. Original passport
4. 4 Photos
5. 16€ stamp (Marca Da Bollo)
6. (last but not least) a document that *proves* you need to go to another country before receiving your new card. I found [this](http://questure.poliziadistato.it/statics/50/all.-4---rilascio-permesso-di-soggiorno-provvisorio.pdf?lang=it) module from the website of [Questura](http://questure.poliziadistato.it/it/Ferrara/articolo/5730dd9e06d11946791430) that you need to fill - regarding the motivation you can see some examples [here](http://permessodisoggiorno.org/permesso-di-soggiorno-provvisorio-e-testimonianza/). Work trip, school trip and reservation of a plane ticket are some of them. In your case I would try asking the host company to send me a sort of invitation letter that could strengthen the request.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how much time I need to wait to get it after I applied?

Comment: Tbh not sure about that but in the third link I provided above someone claims to have received it within 3 days and considering the reason behind its existence (urgency) it makes sense to be issued a lot faster than the normal one.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question. I am planning to go to Denmark with that permit from Italy. However, do you know if I can go out of Schengen zone directly from Denmark, or I have to come back to Italy?

Comment: As long as I know, once issued is a valid residence permit and should follow the same rules as a normal one. Regardless, you could make sure by asking the officer in the questura.